# Ubuntu server "sudo apt-get update" can't resolve security.ubuntu.com

Tags: 14.04

So recently I have been working with Ubuntu and needed to run an update. When I run the command `sudo apt-get update`, it can't resolve `security.ubuntu.com`. But, when I run `ping 8.8.8.8` I get responses. Does anyone know whats going on? NOTE: I am new to Ubuntu and Linux so I am wondering if I'm just doing something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Check whether it's still failing. If so, what does `dig security.ubuntu.com` say?

Comment: connection timed out; no server could be reached

Comment: Is this a server with a desktop environment running Network Manager, or is it the usually preferable blank console; i.e. with no GUI? In either case, how and where did you set the IP address and the all  important DNS nameservers?

Comment: ubuntu is hosted out of virtual box on a windows machine. I know it has a network connection because its assigned an ipv4 address and shows packets from 'ping 8.8.8.8'. Its a console (no GUI). I didn't set any nameservers (I was not aware of this and don't know how to).

Comment: How and where did you set the IP address, gateway, etc.? What does `ifconfig` say the interface is? eth0?

Comment: yes, I let it set defaults (am not aware of entering data for network). The virtual box manages the network adapter and I have used it to port forward for putty and it works fine.

Comment: Sorry. I know little about virtual machines. You have, however, all the signs of missing or faulty DNS nameservers; that is, you can ping by number but not by name.

Comment: ah, ok well thanks for telling me what my problem is in a better stand point

Comment: I don’t think this is a configuration problem, this happens with me all the time. Notworking is fine, but `apt` hangs at security.ubuntu.com for minutes, after which, I suspect, it times out and tries another address.

Answer (score 0):

Check under /etc/network/interfaces. If the Ubuntu is a server version then the interface setup is done here. A desktop version with a GUI would use network manager to configure the interface is high is a link from the top right of the toolbar. At a minimum I would imagine you have "auto lo iface  lo inet loopback and auto eth0 (or em1) iface eth0 (em1) dhcp" if you were to manually setup your connections things would be different but you should still be able to add DNS setting here. Try adding:
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.4
Under the Ethernet interface setting. Save the setting and from the terminal you can try:
sudo service network-interface restart INTERFACE=eth0 (or em1, whichever it was)
another option:
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
Make sure it goes down:
 ifconfig
Then:
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
If things are good you should be able to ping www.google.com
Check under:
man 5 interfaces or man ifconfig for other good info. Hope this helps.